# duplicate key in react spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, animation

I used **react-spring** to animate a list which I display through map function but I noticed that even though I have a unique ID for each row, it keeps giving error that React has issue with two children with the same key.

key was:
`{key: item => item.order.id}`

My question was that how can I fix this issue? I tried to find the answer online but I couldn't find anything useful, so I post it now as I found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that react spring loading the same row 2 times(one is exiting and the same row loading in another row), so I used to get error. In my case, the new row had a different status, So I just mixed the ID and status to build the key and the problem got solved.

`{key: item => item.order.id + item.order.status}`

the old row still exist in the queue but the opacity and height changed to 0, and nobody can see that. That was the reason for getting the error